# Erro jQuery: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, stack

Tenho uma função simples em jQuery, porém está apresentando o erro:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

para exemplficar, são 2 ou 3 links que eu tenho na pagina

```html
<a id="islpronto_link" href="javascript:void(0)" class="bot botchat">Fale Conosco</a>
```

O que está causando este erro?

Abaixo o meu código:

```
$('.botchat').click(function(){
    $('#islpronto_link').click(); 
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Você está sendo vítima de um *loop* infinito.

Veja. Este é seu código.

```
$('.botchat').click(function(){
    $('#islpronto_link').click(); 
    return;
});
```

Todas as vezes que um elemento com a classe **`botchat`** for clicado, ele será disparado. Agora veja esta parte

```
$('#islpronto_link').click();
```

Isso chama o evento de **`click`** do elemento que tem o Id **`islpronto_link`**. Isso faz com que seu código seja executado de novo, e de novo, e de novo...

Na prática, isso é a mesma coisa que fazer

```
function funcao(){
    funcao();    
}
```

Perceba que o código não tem escapatória, a função sempre chama a si própria, infinitamente.

Answer (score -1):

Galera quero agradecer fortemente pela ajuda, acredito que encontrei um caminho nao muito distante do que eu havia pensando anteriormente.
segue um codigo de exemplo

```
<head>
   <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(".bot").click(function(){

                $("#islpronto_link").click();
            });

        });

    </script>

    <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>


<input type="button" class="bot" value="click">

<br/><br/>  
<a id="islpronto_link" class="" href="javascript:void(0)">   teste  </a>
<br/>
<a id="islpronto_link" class="" href="javascript:void(0)">   teste  </a>
<br/>   
<a id="islpronto_link" class="" href="javascript:void(0)">   teste  </a>
<br/>
```

novamente muito obrigado!

Comment: Amigo IDs não podem ser repetidos, a unica coisa que você fez foi colocar a classe em um input, visto por esse angulo parece que você não entende bem ainda DOM e Javascript, ou seja você esta fazendo as coisas aleatoriamente, no chute. Recomendo rever bem porque isto esta falho, só estou lhe dizendo por que quero ajudar.

Comment: entendo, vou dar uma melhorada nisso. grato pela força

Comment: Guilherme,
eu usei a lógica acima apenas para entender como faria, mas acabei fazendo de outra forma, então nao dupliquei os IDs, mas sei que preciso estudar mais JS, novamente agradeço a ajuda.
forte abraço